# Fill a container from several threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, c++14

I want to generate some random data and store it in a container. I split the container into disjoint intervals using iterators and pass them to a thread function (I hope its body isn't important here).

There are several design-related questions here:

1. Is it a good practice to solve such task in this manner?
2. If it is, do I optimally pass and receive parameters in `thread_func`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <utility>

template <typename Iterator, typename Distributions>
void thread_func(Iterator b, Iterator e, Distributions& ds)
{
    // *b++ = something, while b != e
}


int main()
{
    auto nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() ?: 1;
    std::cout << nthreads << " concurrent threads possible" << std::endl;

    const int nevents = 1'000'000;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> events(nevents);

    int nparts = nevents / nthreads;

    std::vector<std::poisson_distribution<>> distributions;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        distributions.emplace_back(5);

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads - 1; i++) {
        auto left  = begin(events) + nparts * i;
        auto right = begin(events) + nparts * (i+1);

        auto f = [l=std::move(left), r=std::move(right), &d=distributions] { thread_func(l, r, d); };

        threads.emplace_back(f);
    }
    auto f = [l=begin(events)+nparts*(nthreads-1), r=end(events), &d=distributions] { thread_func(l, r, d); };
    threads.emplace_back(f);

    for (auto&& t : threads)
        t.join();
}
```

Comment: I learn something new every day: `const int nevents = 100'000'000;`

Comment: If you want to do your users a favor, provide them an environment variable to select the maximum number of threads to be used by your program and only if that variable is not set, fall back to `std::thread::hardware_concurrency`.  Maybe your users have more urgent things to do at the same time and don't want your program to eat up all of their CPUs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Questions

> Is it a good practice to solve such task in this manner?

Yes. Sort of.
Distributing work across threads will get the work done quicker usually (especially when there is no interactions between threads).

**BUT**: The cost of spawning threads is relatively high. Doing it for such a simple problem may not be worth the cost (you should time it and try). So I am going to assume this is a trivial example just for review.

Normally you would spin up your threads into a generic pool. Then send the job to the pool for processing. The threads will continue to live after they have done the job waiting for more jobs to be added to the pool

Secondly this is a very low level interface.

C++ has added the concept of [future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and [promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) as a higher level interface to threading.

> If it is, do I optimally pass and receive parameters in thread_func?

Sure that looks fine.

### Code Review

So here `ds` is a shared resource used by all threads.

```
void thread_func(Iterator b, Iterator e, Distributions& ds)
```

If there is any mutation in this object then any gains can immediately be lost because of contention. So either the usage of this object has to be very well known or it needs to be `const`. To prevent contention you should make that a read only object that is shared across the threads.

So even if there is only 1 for concurrency you are spinning up threads?

```
    auto nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() ?: 1;
```

If you want to use this I would check that you have more than one core available.

```
    auto nthreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    if (nthreads < 2) {
        thread_func(std::begin(events), std::end(events), distributions);
    }
    else // Do it in parallel.
    {
    }
```

Don't rely on statement size scope:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        distributions.emplace_back(5);
```

It is just as easy to write:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        distributions.emplace_back(5);
    }
```

This will protect you from accidental errors.

You don't need to re-calculate these every time.

```
        auto left  = begin(events) + nparts * i;
        auto right = begin(events) + nparts * (i+1);
```

Also if you update your code to use another container (or any generic container) the `operator+` may not work. You should be using `std::advance()`

```
auto  segmentBegin = begin(events);
auto  segmentEnd   = segmentBegin;
std::advance(segmentEnd, nparts);

for (int i = 0; i < nthreads - 1; i++) {
   threads.emplace_back([l=segmentBegin, r=segmentEnd, &d=distributions] { thread_func(l, r, d); });

    
    segmentBegin = segmentEnd;
    std::advance(segmentEnd, nparts);
}
threads.emplace_back([l=segmentBegin, r=std::end(events), &d=distributions] { thread_func(l, r, d); });
```

Iterators are very cheap objects.

```
 l=std::move(left), r=std::move(right)
```

don't see the need to move them.

Comment: Actually, the OP's code already handles the `nthreads == 1` case almost smartly by looping only to `nthreads - 1` and filling the remainder after the loop.  It is that last thread that should never be created (for any value of `nthreads`) because there is no good reason to have the main thread sit idle while the workers do their part.

Comment: For the `ds` parameter: Since it is instantiated to a `std::bernoulli_distribution`, accessing it from different threads concurrently invokes undefined behavior.  But the distribution object is lightweight: just pass it by value.  Its internal state is not interesting anyways.

Comment: Thank you for review. It is my fault that the first question sounds too blurry. I didn't meant to ask about how to make general high-performance applications, only about using iterators to disjoint parts vs. own container for each thread.

Comment: As you and @5gon12eder correctly noted, distributions should be passed by value, because they are stateful. And thanks for advice on `std::advance`.

Comment: @LeoTolstoy: I'd actually suggest you keep using `operator+` when it makes the code more readable.  Using a non-random-access container would be a huge mistake for this code, so a compile-time error when there's no `operator+` is actually a *good* thing.  `std::advance` docs say it uses `operator+` if available, otherwise loops on `operator++`.